# Equivalent statments in Java for C# formated string cout

Tags: c#, java

What is the Java equivalent instruction for the following statements:

```
String name;
cout << "So your name is  " << name << endl;
```

Or in C#

```
console.writeline("So your name is {0} ", name);
```

Comment: Google _Hello World in Java_

Comment: Something is wrong and i cant edit it 
the first statement is
cout<<" string  " <<stringvar <<endl;

Comment: im asking about the formatted string output which i couldn't find in typical hello world tutorials

Comment: (There is no "formatting" here, only "outputting". Follow jlordo's advice. In any case, look at `String.format` for "formatting".)

Comment: My question is about FORMATTED output

Comment: @HSN Then it would be best if your future questions contained relevant code.

Comment: You need 

    System.out.format("So your name is %s%n", name);
 Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html

Comment: System.out.println(java.text.MessageFormat.format("So your name is {0} ", name));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String name;
cout<<"So your name is  "<<name<<endl;
```

is equivalent to:

```
String name = ...;
System.out.println("So your name is " + name);
```

---

and:

```
Console.WriteLine("So your name is {0}", name);
```

is equivalent to:

```
System.out.printf("So your name is %s", name);
```

Comment: @HSN Anytime :) You can accept this answer as the right answer if you wish.

Comment: I did once i saw it , but a message said that i have to wait for 10 mins to do so  , i will accept it  once  i can